# Was Reznov actually in Mason's imagination in Black Ops 1?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Reznov is said to have been a hallucination to Mason after he got captured in Vorkuta. But how could Mason possibly do all those missions alone?

Did Reznov never make it out alive from Vorkuta? There must be some signs of him surviving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viktor Reznov did not survive the escape from Vorkuta.

From the [Fandom wiki page on Reznov](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Viktor_Reznov):

> Reznov continued to lead the insurrection, securing a secret weapon for Mason to blow their way out. He pulled Mason out of a tear gas barrage and the two escaped on motorcycles. Mason managed to escape by leaping onto a train, however Reznov stayed behind. He had sacrificed himself to free Mason, stating that Mason deserved the freedom knowing he would carry on to go after Dragovich. When Mason told Reznov to jump onto the train to freedom, Reznov exclaimed, "For you, Mason. Not for me." He was killed by the pursuing soldiers.

This is corroborated by Hudson

> During Mason's interrogation, Hudson revealed that the real Viktor Reznov had been dead for five years, having been killed in the escape from Vorkuta. Having brainwashed Mason, Reznov was able to complete his personal objective of killing Dragovich, Kravchenko and Steiner; leading Mason to become obsessed with pursuing them in spite of his other objectives, inadvertently continuing Reznov's posthumous legacy. The Reznov witnessed by Mason was a guardian angel-like hallucination, possibly developed by multiple personality disorder.

There's evidence during the missions where Mason sees Reznov that he isn't really there. Reznov randomly disappears and reappears, and others are not aware of his presence:

> Reznov fought alongside Mason, but went missing during the American incursion into Laos. He reappeared after Mason's helicopter crashes, stating that Woods was a good man and that Mason had chosen his friends well. He met up with Mason again inside the Viet Cong tunnels. At this point, Swift turned around and asked what was wrong with Mason, seemingly oblivious to his contact with Reznov.

Reznov was indeed just a hallucination. Mason did those missions without him.

Comment: I remember this was such an insane twist in the Black Ops series.  Black Ops 1 and 2 as well as the World at War precursor to the series were some of the best CoDs.

Comment: @TimmyJim I find most CoD players tend to either really like the Treyarch games or really like the Infinity Ward games, but not both. I'd say World at War was good, but each Black Ops game has taken the series to new lows. The BO campaign started well but got stupider the further it went. MW didn't reach that level of absurdity until the third one, if even then.